# It's a question of Electrostatics, where the force on dipole is to be determined by using the potential energy

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, dipole

$\text{In Electrostatics :: Force on Dipole : }$
$$\vec F = - \nabla U, \,\,\ \text{U= Potential Energy of Dipole}$$
$\because U=-\vec p \cdot \vec E$
$\text{How can we come to this result : }$
$$\vec F = \nabla (\vec p \cdot \vec E)=(\vec p \cdot \nabla) \vec E$$

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, your formula is for the rotational potential energy of a dipole in a uniform E field.  You might find a torque = dU/dθ. Other wise there is the question of what force are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  If you are asking why the last two equations are equivalent, use the vector identity
$$
\vec{\nabla} (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}) = (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\vec{B} + (\vec{B} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\vec{A} + \vec{A} \times (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B}) + \vec{B} \times (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{A})
$$
with appropriate simplifications based on the properties of $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{E}$.

Answer (score 0):

First understand that this is only for an uniform  electric field as in non uniform electric field potential energy will be vary as there will be both a torque and a force with different line of actions now as the condition you may have understood
But now the force has come into play which is variable that means this is based upon a non uniform electric field
Now as Michael has answered using the vector quantity you can have that but for more basic concept  the partial derivative indicates that this the force is variable as I have stated . So maybe this can help you